# IIS redirect with and without trailing slash

Tags: iis, redirect

I have made a rewrite map and what the entries to match both the target address with or without the trailing slash.

Example:

/about-us/page
/about-us/page/

I have tried with adding a trailing slash in the match like:
{redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}
{redirects:{REQUEST_URI}/}

And matching any, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?